# MSSQL datetime object won't echo out the correct date if i remove its var_dump

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, sqlsrv, var-dump

I'm trying to create a simple table displaying data from June 2019, however i'm having trouble getting the MSSQL datetime row to echo out correctly whenever i remove my var_dump line.

So with the var_dump i get the correct dates but without all my columns show up as a date from 1970 which doesn't exist, however when i do a vardump of the Transaction date first, i get the correct result on all lines??

Is this something to do with me needing to change the format of the row to a format that PHP can understand?

Here's an example of the input 2016-07-04 00:00:00.000

Below is my code.

```
    <?php
$serverName = "SQL,1433";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );


$sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [all sales data]";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
?>

<?php var_dump( $row['Transaction Date']);?>

<tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Order Point Account'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Analysis Category'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Branch Code'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo date("d m Y", strtotime($row['Transaction Date']->date));?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Product Discount Group'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['End Product Cost of Sale'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['End Product Other Value'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['End Product Sales Value'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['End Product Analysis Quantity'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Invoice Account'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Magic Number'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Order Number'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['PAC Level 1'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['PAC Level 2'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['PAC Level 3'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['PAC Level 4'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Product Code'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Salesman 1'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Statement Account'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Supplier Account'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Contact']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Order Source'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['User'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Customer Order No'];?></td>
                </tr>

            <?php
            }
            ?>


            </tbody>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

below is the vardump

> object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-07-04 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/London" }

Here's the result of print_r($row);

> Array ( [Order Point Account] =>  [Analysis Category] => AD [Branch Code] => 100 [Transaction Date] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2016-07-04 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/London ) [Product Discount Group] =>  [End Product Cost of Sale] => 165.19999694824 [End Product Other Value] => 165.2 [End Product Sales Value] => 369.60000610352 [End Product Analysis Quantity] => 1 [Invoice Account] =>  [Magic Number] => 800713 [Sales Order Line Number] => [Order Number] => 319651 [PAC Level 1] => d [PAC Level 2] => dLB [PAC Level 3] => dLB01 [PAC Level 4] => dLB0106 [Product Code] =>  [Salesman 1] => 9500 [Statement Account] =>  [Supplier Account] =>  [Contact] => fax [Order Source] => FAX [User] =>  [Customer Order No] =>  )

Comment: `TOP` without `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Not sure how the specific error comes about … But if you have a DateTime instance already, then you should use the format method of that directly, rather than using strtotime to first parse it into a timestamp and then format that again using date …

Comment: @Sami i Will do that after the date field echo's correctly.

Comment: @04FS Would you be able to give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use PHP driver for SQL Server, not PDO version, you can [retrieve date and time types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-date-and-time-type-as-strings-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-2017) (datetime, date, time, datetime2, and datetimeoffset) as strings or as PHP datetime objects by specifying `ReturnDatesAsStrings` option in the connection string:

```
<?php 
...
$serverName = "SQL,1433";
$connectionInfo = array(
    "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>false,
    // Set to TRUE if you want to get date values as string.
    //"ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true,
    "Database"=>'database',
    "UID"=>"username",
    "PWD"=>"password"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
...
?>
```

By default, `ReturnDatesAsStrings` is `false`, so you just need to format datetime object.

```
<?php
...
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   ...
   // Format date with procedural or object oriented style:
   <td><?php echo date_format($row['Transaction Date'], 'd m Y');?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['Transaction Date']->format('d m Y');?></td>
   ...
}
...

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly, your a life saver!

Comment: @Chris Glad to help!